# Write to a txt file in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I write to file data in this way.

I call out this function many times.

```
String ResultString = "data";
byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ResultString);

StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFolder dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("DataFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
StorageFile file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync("Data.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
    s.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
}
```

The compiler skips StorageFile.
Why dataFolder and local have the values NULL??

Comment: Is it null while debugging it? or are you getting a `NRE`?

Comment: so, when debugging is null.
But if you go through all the features of this application turns off.

Comment: Please be clear about your issue. This code block works fine.

Comment: compiler only sometimes performs all the functions.
sometimes when you perform all the functions of this application shuts down

Comment: wrap it in a `try{}catch(){}` and let us know what the error is (and where)

Comment: try and catch nothing displays

Comment: Could you post again the code with the try catch? And did you try to enable a breakpoint inside catch?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `async` and `await` as it needs to be asynchronous.

```
 public static async Task<string> WriteFie()
    {
      string message = "abc";
      StorageFolder local =  Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
      StorageFolder dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("DataFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
      StorageFile file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync("Data.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
      await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, message);
    }
```